# How to connect to a remote pc using socket in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, ipv6

I am trying to connect my python socket programs on two remote PCs using IPv6. I am not using IPv4 because I understand that my external and internal IPs will be different due to my router using NAT. I thought that because my visible temporary IPv6 (whatismyipaddress.com) is same as Temp IPv6 my system shows (ipconfig /all), both sockets will easily connect over internet. But still server is not receiving any connection request from client. I have configured firewall to not block the code. I can't find any more info on IPv6.

Server code-

```
import socket

s = socket.create_server(('myTempIPv6', 50000), family = socket.AF_INET6)

connection, address = s.accept()

print("Conncted with the client\nWaiting for Client's msg...")


while True:
    try:
        print("Client's msg: " + connection.recv(1024).decode())
    except ConnectionResetError:
        print('Disconnected from client!')
        break

    msg = input("Your msg: ")
    connection.sendall(msg.encode())
```

Client code -

```
import socket

connection = socket.create_connection(('myTempIPv6', 50000))

print('Conncted with the server')

while True:
    msg = input("Your msg: ")

    try:
        connection.sendall(msg.encode())
    except ConnectionResetError:
        print('Connection closed by the server!')
        break

    print("Server's msg: " + connection.recv(1024).decode())
```

I've confirmed them working on LAN, but no response on Internet, please help!!

Comment: Check how your router handles IPv6. Most home routers filter inbound IPv6 traffic.

Comment: is there a way to disable it @KlausD.

Comment: Network and router configuration is not on-topic for Stack Overflow. Also I would not advise to do so.

Comment: is there any way I can connect my python program to a remote client? @KlausD.

Comment: Again, this is a site about programming. Configuring the networking is off-topic. And BTW you don't connect to a client, a client connects to a server.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issues is caused by the network, not the code.

Answer (score -2):

you have to open your server pc connection to WAN or WIFI network device, and make it discoverable. you then have to type in your public ip, with the following port with port forwarding enabled